# Positioning from fixed to static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to have a fixed `div` on screen only between certain points, defined by whether certain elements are on top of the screen or not.

I tried to accomplish it by changing the `position` via JQuery. The problem I found is, at the bottom point, when I change the position from `fixed` to `static`, the div jumps away, instead of start scrolling from that point on.

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/woroyejahe/5/

Thanks

Comment: Then set it to relative!

Comment: Thanks, but it still jumps away. The idea is that the fixed div starts to scroll from that point on, together with other element at the same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) of the lower `div` and set it as the `top` for your CSS style with `position: absolute`.

Comment: Great! I just needed to tweak a conditional and now got it working! Thank you very much.